# CSS Issue - Wrapping

Tags: css, background, wrapper

I'm trying to wrap my website differently so that the background is divided in 2. The gray part which is the main background but also a white part which is smaller and wrap the main-content.

Basically I'd like [this](http://frenchegg.com) to look like [this](http://frenchegg.com/images/home.jpg).

I'm not quite sure how to add the images to create that shadow effect and I also don't know how to create that white wrapper.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right taken a look. Let me know the outcome.

```
.main-content{
   background:#FFFFFF;
   width:90%;
   margin:0% 4% 0% 5%;
}
```

easy solve method:

```
.main-content{
    -webkit-box-shadow:0px 0px 3px 5px #000000;
    -moz-box-shadow:0px 0px 3px 5px #000000;
    -o-box-shadow:0px 0px 3px 5px #000000;
    box-shadow:0px 0px 3px 5px #0000000;
}
```

Or the gradient you asked for:

```
.main-content:before{
    background:-webkit-linear-gradient(top,rgba(0,0,0,1) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,0) 100%);
    background:-moz-linear-gradient(top,rgba(0,0,0,1) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,0) 100%);
    background:-o-linear-gradient(top,rgba(0,0,0,1) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,0) 100%);
    background:-ms-linear-gradient(top,rgba(0,0,0,1) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0) 100%);
    background:linear-gradient(top,rgba(0,0,0,1) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0) 100%);
    content:'';
    z-index:98;
    position:relative;
    width:105%;
    height:400px;
    left:-2%;
}
```

But this gradient method only really works for browsers that support the 'webkits' and their updated counter parts. But I haven't really tested it so you might want to play around with it etc. And if you don't like it try the `box-shadow` method :)

You'll need to adjust the element `div.bann` to correct some positioning errors. theres a in the element because the element is taller than the image.

```
.bann{
    width:90%;
    height:auto;/*probably can remove this*/
    margin:0% 4% 0% 5%;
    padding:0px;
} 
.bann>img{/*not required if you haven't adjusted the image. You can remove this completely.*/
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
}
```

Comment: Yes the image should be partially hidden.

Comment: hmm also it seems like my design is still broken if you look at the page.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't recommend using an image. Too large. Heres two methods. Don't forget that `rgba()` doesn't work in [lte ie 8] (I think?). Also I've used the `:before` pseudo so that it's placed before the element but you may find this wouldn't be necessary. But using the pseudo element you can then position your effect.

```
#element:before{
    background:-webkit-linear-gradient(top,rgba(0,0,0,1) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,0) 100%);
    background:-moz-linear-gradient(top,rgba(0,0,0,1) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,0) 100%);
    background:-o-linear-gradient(top,rgba(0,0,0,1) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,0) 100%);
    background:-ms-linear-gradient(top,rgba(0,0,0,1) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0) 100%);
    background:linear-gradient(top,rgba(0,0,0,1) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0) 100%);
    content:'';
}
#element{
    background:#CCCCCC;
}
```

And for ie (I would really recommend it. To be honest I wouldn't bother with ie lol) use only hex colours using your background colour for the body.

```
#element{
    background:linear-gradient(top,#000000 0%, #CCCCCC 100%);
}
```

Besides lte ie 9 can't use the linear-gradient property anyway!

Another method is to use `box-shadow` but this wouldn't achieve the transparent gradient you're looking for.

```
#element{
    box-shadow:0px 0px 3px #000000;
}
```

Comment: I followed your recommendations however my website looks a little bit messed up now.

Comment: @LouisG.Talbot sorry! lol I didn't really provide the positioning etc. It's difficult to explain. I'll take another look at your website and give you the positioning and elements etc.